# Proper way to get EPOCH timestamp in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, epoch

I want to get the EPOCH timestamp in kotlin in "seconds":"nanoseconds" format.

**Note: Please look at the accepted answer for the right solution.**

**Edit:**

It's my current solution and I'm sure there would be some better way to achieve this,

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

fun main() {
    val epochNanoseconds = ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.now())
    val epochSeconds = epochNanoseconds/1.seconds.inWholeNanoseconds
    val remainingFractionOfNanoSeconds = epochNanoseconds%1.seconds.inWholeNanoseconds
    println("$epochSeconds:$remainingFractionOfNanoSeconds")
}
```

example output:

```
1670251213:849754000
```

Another example (from the comments): For 1670251213 seconds 50000 nanoseconds, also known as 1670251213.00005 seconds in decimal, I want `1670251213:50000` (means :).

Is there any way to get seconds and remaining nanoseconds directly from `java.time.Instant` or any other library available to achieve this conveniently?

Solution from the accepted answer:

```
import java.time.Instant

fun main() {
    val time = Instant.now()
    println("${time.epochSecond}:${time.nano}")
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "seconds and remaining nanoseconds"? Do you want a count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z, plus the count of nanoseconds in the fractional second since then?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes exactly

Comment: Then why do you have 18 digits in the fractional part of your example output? Nanoseconds use only 9 digits. If your example is in error, edit your Question to correct it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need too accurate. Somewhat millisec accurate is ok but I need that format to satisfy some json schema. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are working too hard.

Ask the `Instant` object for its count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z. Make a string of that, append the COLON character. Then append the count of nanoseconds in the fractional second of the `Instant`.

```
instant.getEpochSecond() 
+ ":" 
+ instant.getNano()
```

> 1670220134:130848

## Details

Neither the legacy date-time classes (`Calendar`, `Date`, etc.) nor the modern *java.time* classes support [International Atomic Time (TAI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) that you requested. Time-keeping on conventional computers (and therefore Java) is nowhere near as accurate as an atomic clock.

Perhaps you used that term loosely, and really just want a count of nanoseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen with an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) of zero hours-minutes-seconds (1970-01-01T00:00Z) within the limits of conventional computer hardware.

If so, the `Instant` class will work for you. But beware of limitations in the implementations of Java based on the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) codebase.

- In Java 8, the first with *java.time* classes, the current moment is captured with a resolution of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).
- In Java 9+, the current moment is captured with a resolution of [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) (generally, depending on the limits of your computer hardware).

Note that in all versions (8, 9, and later), an `Instant` is capable of [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. The limitations bulleted above relate to *capturing the current moment* from the computer hardware clock.

The internal representation of a moment in the `Instant` class comprises two parts:

- A count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
- A fractional second represented by a count of nanoseconds.

The `Instant` class provides a pair of accessor methods (getters) to see both of these numbers.

- [`getEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond())
- [`getNano`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#getNano())

Your Question is not entirely clear, you seem to be asking for those two numbers with a COLON character between them.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
String nanos = Long.toString( instant.getNano() ) ;
String output = 
    instant.getEpochSecond() 
    + ":" 
    + instant.getNano()
;
```

> instant.toString(): 2022-12-05T06:12:33.294698Z
>
> output: 1670220753:294698

If you want to pad zeros to the right of your fractional second, use `String.format`.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
String nanos = Long.toString( instant.getNano() ) ;
String output = 
    instant.getEpochSecond() 
    + ":" 
    + String.format( "%1$" + nanos.length() + "s", nanos ).replace(' ', '0') // Pad with leading zeros if needed.
;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/gdMi38).

> instant.toString(): 2022-12-05T06:12:33.294698Z
>
> output: 1670220753:294698000

Alternatively, you could instantiate a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) object.

Comment: does the solution include leap seconds?

Comment: @Vencat No, leap seconds are ignored. That makes sense in the context of calendaring as the purpose of leap seconds is to slow the clock to let the calendar (year-month-day) catch up. If you really need leap seconds, which would be quite unusual, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access its [`org.threeten.extra.scale`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/scale/package-summary.html) package.